# PHP/SQL Dealing with special characters (PHP Beginner)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to build a simple search function in php that searches values in a SQL database.

My code seems to work ok so far, however I have some issues with special characters. For example I don't get any search results, as far as I can tell, the search is executed as the die command is not called.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE attribute LIKE '%$input%';") 
or die("Could not search");
```

I think the issue is that `$input` is a string which can contain things like a&b. How do i deal with this?

Additionally the database contains some French words, so I have to deal with all the `é,ç,ô` etc. How do I make sure the outputs from the database that contain special characters, for example `hôtel`, are correctly displayed through php?

UPDATE

After spending hours trying to figure out what the issue is, I've found some indications where things might go wrong. Initially I had thought that escaping caused the problems, this does not seem to be the case...

My code creates a string `$query_in` which is then passed using

```
mysql_query($query_in);
```

I echoed the `$query_in` string for debugging:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE attribute1 LIKE 
"%a & b%" OR attribute2 LIKE "%a & b%" OR
attribute3 LIKE "%a & b%" OR attribute4
LIKE "%Ta & b%" OR attribute5 LIKE "%a & b%"
OR attribute6 LIKE "%a & b%"
```

If I manually run (copy&paste) this query in the phpMyadmin interface it works just fine and I get results. However, when I check for empty return values from the database using:

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

`echo $count` returns 0

How can that be? Also, rest assured I'll switch things over to msqli after this is fixed ;)

Comment: Apply these two things.

1- You need to define the collation of your table to be utf8_general_ci.

2- You need to define the 'mysql_set_charset('utf8');' in the file where you made connection with the database and right after the selection of database like 'mysql_select_db' use this 'mysql_set_charset' this will allow you to add and retrieve data properly in what ever the language it is. After that just simply perform the search by using mysql_real_escape_string and you will have what is required. Cheers

Comment: guys, guys! No one there to warn our young friend [not to use mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `utf8_encode`

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE attribute LIKE '%".utf8_encode($input)."%';") or die("Could not search");
```

**Or** by adding this line with database connection,

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8", $database_name);
```

Suggestion : don't use mysql it's deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

to deal with special character use addslash or mysql escape function

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE attribute LIKE '%" . addslashes($input) . "%';") or die("Could not search");
```

OR

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE attribute LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($input) . "%';") or die("Could not search");
```